# PHP NTLM authentication of current user on different host fails using cURL

Tags: php, ntlm, php-curl

I'm using PHP 7.1.7 with cURL 7.54.1 on one of the servers on the local network, and due to the development requirements, I have to be able to access files stored on another local network server (PHP 4.3 or some such). Due to version requirements of some of the other components of my system, I have to keep the script on the newer server, and files it accesses on the older one.
I use the following settings to pass the current NTLM user credentials from source server where this script resides to the destination server - and it's supposed to work, but somehow it doesn't:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ":");
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: -1");
header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");    
header('Content-Type: '.get_mime_type($fileresult['filename']));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileresult['originalname'].'"');
$contents = file_get_contents_curl($path);
$localSize = strlen($contents);
header('Content-Length: ' . $localSize);
echo $contents;
ob_flush();
flush();
exit();
```

When I'm explicitly specifying my

> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "[username]:[password]");

, it works flawlessly, but when trying to re-use existing user credentials - it fails. As an admin, I don't want to leave my credentials in the code as plain text - that's blatant security violation, and creating dummy user profile with access rights to those files would prevent the proper logging of actual user activity on the older server - which is a security concern in itself.

I found this bug report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62195 for the same issue, but it was related to completely different version of PHP (5.4.3), and I did take into consideration the developer's comments there - still no use.

Is there any curl_setopt setting that I am forgetting to set properly to make it work? Perhaps IIS server may need a certain config change to allow PHP to re-use those credentials in cURL request? Or should it work as it currently is, and my next step would be to submit a bug report to php.net?

Appreciate your help!

---

Edit:

No matter which file I request using the code above (with inherited username and password), the script returns a 1.3k file with the expected file name and extension (.PDF, .PNG or any other), but containing exactly the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

cURL returns no error - according to it everything is perfectly fine.
When I'm explicitly specifying username and password all the returned files have their own expected unique size and contents.

Comment: I see no error checking in your code. What does curl_error() tell you? What do the webserver logs (where the authentication is being validated) tell you?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "re-use existing user credentials" and "inherited username and password" ? Are you trying to authenticate with the user running PHP itself ? Two major reasons for NTLM failure : either the connection is not kept alive during the 3-steps (Send Type 1 request, Receive Type 2 response, Send Type 3 request), or simply bad credentials (username/password/domain).

Comment: by Existing user credentials I mean the user that is opening this web-page in browser. Since this is all inside an AD domain on a local network - the server authenticates the user on page load. The file that I'm trying to retrieve is stored on a different server, but within the same domain so same username and password as already entered grant access to it as well - or not, depending on the user and their specific permissions. Those are the credentials that I want to provide from server 1 with PHP script to server 2 with stored files using cURL

Comment: @AlexLutsky By design you can't access (and then reuse) the NTLM credentials because the client answers to a challenge, it doesn't send the credentials themselves. It was asked and answered not so clearly already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9249572/7748072). What you maybe can do, is to **forward** the request then your PHP doesn't require authentication, and let the final application authenticate. We would try adding the HTTP headers that you want to add (Content-Disposition + Cache-Control). Add a Tag for the web server you are using (IIS / Apache), and we'll elaborate a solution.

Comment: But the second server will probably ask for the credentials to the end-user, at least on the first access.

Comment: Based on [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62195), if you look at the comments by mike@php.net, he indirectly confirms that this behavior is expected under certain conditions - where he lists at least one such condition which I already employed, although it didn't produce the desired result - but perhaps in the newer version of PHP these requirements changed.

Comment: @AlexLutsky you already gave this in the Question itself and we don't have any proof this has worked for anyone (if lucky, maybe someone will bring the solution here). I agree that requesting on the same host might work, as in your link, because NTLM authenticates a connection and not a request. As long as the connection is opened, the server requesting itself, I don't see any reason that it would break the rules and not work. But you don't have any connection opened to another server, and a new connection to this server will need to be authenticated by this server, with its own challenge.

Answer (score 0):

> and it's supposed to work, but somehow it doesn't

No, it's not supposed to work for different servers, as explained in the comments.

To avoid authenticating twice, which could a bit difficult to implement, and not desirable for the end-user, I have the following idea.

Maybe can you just rely on authenticating on the second server (PHP 4) only, the first server (PHP 7) not configured for asking credentials but forwarding the NTLM messages to the second server and then starting a session (cookie) when it knows the user has finally succeeded to authenticate. One side-effect is that all new sessions would start by forwarding a request to the second server. Probably you can do all that in PHP, but I didn't try myself and it costs too much time unfortunately.